# This tag is [overcommit]ted

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

I stumbled upon a question having [overcommit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/overcommit) tag. Currently there are 25 questions and it has no description.

From what I can gather, the questions are about evenly split between two completely different concepts:

- [A Ruby tool for managing Git hooks](https://github.com/brigade/overcommit)
- [Memory overcommitment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_overcommitment) - trying to grab more memory than is available.

I'm not even sure but it's possible there are two variations of the second thing - trying to allocate memory in, say C using something like `malloc` and memory in virtual machines. Although I'm not even sure if those are two separate topics but it seemed a bit like it.

At any rate, what is `[overcommit]` about - the library that deals with Git or to do with memory? And should there be a different tag for the other topic(s)?

Comment: Nobody asks a question with *only* the [overcommit] tag.  It will be preceded with a primary tag, like [ruby], [c], [git].  Which makes the context clear.  We like questioners using multiple tags, a primary tag like [c] is important but far too broad.

Comment: But isn't the concepts just too different? I'd understand something like `[arrays]` - an array in C, in Java and JavaScript can behave differently but, broadly, they are about the same thing. If one understands the concepts behind an array, they'd be able to understand it in almost any context. But if you know all about memory overcommitment, you may not even understand Git and vice versa. Are there other tags that are *completely* different and have no transferable knowledge between different contexts?

Comment: Questioners use tags to select an audience for their problem.  That's where that job ends.  Indexing content so the Q+A is useful to other programmers is Google's job.  It doesn't use tags.

Comment: Still seems strange to use the same tag for a git hook management tool and a memory management issue, one or both of them should perhaps be renamed and given a proper wiki.

Comment: @HansPassant yes, "audience" here is the key. As I said, there can be audience for `[arrays]` even in different languages. Similarly `[functional programming]` will use the same ideas across different languages, so one fluent in that paradigm can answer most questions regardless of context. Who is the target audience for `[overcommit]` - people who deal with Git or people who deal with memory management? Or are you suggesting it's both? And again I ask - are there other examples of tags that have completely separate audiences that are in wide use?

Comment: He does not want answers from everybody that, say, know the [c] language.  He wants only those people that know what "overcommit" means when you write a C program.  So not from you.  Not that this has to slow you down, spending a couple of hours on researching the topic tends to be quite useful and may well produce a useful answer.  One of the most powerful SO features, discovering concepts that were unfamiliar to you but might well be useful in your own code.

Comment: @HansPassant so, I take it that you don't have an example of any other tag that is used this way. Doesn't that mean that tags shouldn't be entirely context dependent as none of the others is?

Comment: @HansPassant actually I researched some, as you suggested, and [found this on meta-tags](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/) - they are discouraged. The `[overcommit]` seems like a clear case of that. `1. If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question` - it absolutely cannot. `2. If the tag commonly means different things to different people` it absolutely does. You've confirmed both with your own words. So, how come this tag *which is at odds with how tags should work* is fine according to you? Unless, again, you have examples of such tags being widely accepted

Comment: @HansPassant Having a single tag refer to multiple completely unrelated topics greatly diminishes the value of having tags in the first place.

Comment: This tag is [overcommit]ted.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm that might have been a much better title for this question :)

Comment: Agreed that tags shall not be deliberately ambiguous. I suggest retagging the Ruby related ones to [ruby-overcommit] or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a bit confusing about which one to keep and which one to retag, as both the usages had nearly *equal* number of tags (10 for the ruby one, 15 for the memory one). Therefore, I created two tags for them:

- [memory-overcommitment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-overcommitment) – I took the name from the Wikipedia page that was linked in the original post. I added the [overcommit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/overcommit) as a synonym to this, in order to prevent users from recreating the tag.
- [ruby-overcommit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-overcommit) – I used this name from Mr. Lister's comment below the original post. We can rename it if there is a need.

I also did some cleanup, and deleted (around 7) few completely off topic posts. As of now there are no tag wikis, therefore that is the next task.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, there is no tag wiki, and therefore there is no definitive answer. It can be used for anything that is related to `overcommit`.